# How to deal with bounty questions that are duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, declined-flags, bounty

How should we deal with questions that have a duplicate, yet are protected from being closed by a bounty?

This question has been [asked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253612/when-a-question-with-a-bounty-is-a-duplicate), and the answer was to leave a comment pointing out the previous duplicate question, give the author the opportunity to dispute it, and then raise a moderator flag explaining the situation.

I performed all of these steps upon encountering a [duplicate bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439615/which-layout-should-be-used-to-show-a-footer-depending-on-the-rest-of-the-scre), but the flag was declined.

My flag was as follows:

> This bounty question is a duplicate of [View inside ScrollView doesn't take all place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211338/view-inside-scrollview-doesnt-take-all-place) and although it's a pretty straightforward question, no one has provided the correct answer yet (Kiril Aleksandrov's answer is incorrect). It should probably be closed as a duplicate, and the bounty refunded.

It was declined with the following comment:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I would like to have a definite answer on whether flagging is appropriate in this situation, as I have just been blocked from flagging due to two moderator flags being declined which were raised a week ago.

Comment: No answer to your question at all, but IMHO NAA, maybe an worth  an 
*Other flag*  is the accepted [answer on the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27605660/1699210)

Comment: I'm surprised the flag was declined, actually. Perhaps a mod will chime in.

Comment: Ah, the bounty period has already ended. There is no point in refunding the bounty now and can properly close the question tomorrow after the grace period ends.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm not completely sure, but I think the flag was declined _before_ the bounty period ended. In any case, it would have been nice to mark it as helpful instead of declining it (and causing my flags to be blocked).

Comment: When you flag for a moderator, remember they see hundreds (or thousands) of flags in a day. Your flag should be short, to the point, and tell them what you would like them to do. In this case, a a better flag might be *Bounty protected duplicate of <link> that can't be closed by normal means. Can a mod remove the bounty to allow closure?*, which does not take long to read, is clear and concise, and immediately shows what your flag is requesting. Moderators don't have the time to do a lot of reading (or research) because of volume. Succinct and clear flags help immensely.

Comment: While I agree with what your thoughts @KenWhite, that declined message is not particularly helpful and in this case the decline caused a negative effect for the OP who flagged it. The OP's flag message would not have taken significantly longer to read even if someone was spending hours a day going through flags. If there was a way to "dismiss" a flag where it simply would be too much trouble to sort out would be better as the OP didn't do anything wrong (from my understanding).

Comment: @Turnerj: The declined message is clear, because the flag is unclear. The decline did not result in a negative effect for the OP who flagged it, because there is no "negative effect" for not being able to flag (there are thousands of people here who cannot flag). There's a vast difference between "This is wrong because of this reason. Please do this thing." and "Here is this long paragraph of some stuff. Maybe somewhere you'll find information." when you're seeing a lot of things in your list of things to do. If the flag is not clear and precise, there's no reason to waste time reading it.

Comment: @KenWhite, is a flag block only for the moderator/other flag or all flags? (eg. too broad, off topic, duplicate). If it is for all, I would still think that is a negative effect, potentially 2 slightly longer worded flags stop you from being able to say correctly select "unsalvageable" option for a Q in the Triage review queue. I get that a mod's time is valuable, after [having a check of the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), I think it might be worthwhile saying what you wrote in your comment that those flags should be short/concise.

Comment: @KenWhite, how much more concise than "This bounty question is a duplicate of…" do you really want? Any mod who reads even just that far will understand what's up, and then the rest just clarifies.

Comment: @KenWhite: In my opinion, all the information in my flag was relevant. I stated that it was a straightforward question, as if it had been a complex question then there might be room for multiple answers, and there would have been a case for retaining the bounty. I stated that the sole existing answer was incorrect, as otherwise there would seem to be an alternative legitimate solution, and the bounty might be retained. I tried to make it as concise as I could without sacrificing grammar (which might make it hard to understand), while providing all the information needed to make the decision.

Comment: @Turnerj: All the flags are suspended, not only moderator flags. I discovered these declined flags when I was blocked from flagging an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656612/android-service-background/27656701#27656701) as "not an answer" yesterday.

Comment: «This bounty question is a duplicate of View inside ScrollView doesn't take all place and although it's a pretty straightforward question, no one has provided the correct answer yet (Kiril Aleksandrov's answer is incorrect). It should probably be closed as a duplicate, and the bounty refunded.» -> «This bounty question is a duplicate of View inside ScrollView doesn't take all place and though it's pretty straightforward, no one has answered correctly yet. It should be closed as a duplicate, and the bounty refunded.».

Comment: This shortens it by a line without sacrificing grammar, though I removed the bracketed bit. That said, I agree that the response was inappropriate. Call it a "long paragraph", it's only 4 lines. Another idea might have been to split lines, but maybe this is now allowed.

Comment: @Nathan: I suggested how much more concise previously. I guess you missed it, so here: *Bounty protected duplicate of <link> that can't be closed by normal means. Can a mod remove the bounty to allow closure?*. Two short, clear sentences. At least a dozen fewer words, makes the same point, and explains what action you'd like the mod to take. This is what has been suggested in previous posts here and at Meta SE by mods such as Shog9, BoltClock, and George Stocker as what they'd like to see in custom flags.

Comment: Corsair992: Yes, of course *in your opinion* your flag was perfect. In the moderator's opinion, it was not and therefore it was declined. It's amazing to me that people post here asking for input as to why something happened and then argue or disagree with everyone's input that doesn't just say *You were perfect, and you should change nothing. Everyone else is wrong.* If you don't want to hear input here, why did you bother to post the question asking for it in the first place?

Comment: @KenWhite, yes, I saw your suggestion. It did not and does not seem substantially different; the first and last parts are substantially similar, and it's only the middle dozen or so words that are taken out. Declining a flag on the basis that reading an extra dozen words of clarification in the middle is too hard is a mistake. Mind you, there is *no difference* with your suggested version until the issue was already explained: anyone reading, then, would already know what was up at the same point either way.

Comment: @Nathan: There's more difference than that, and I don't see how you can miss it. My suggestion also **clearly states what is being asked of the moderator**, and doesn't obscure it in the other text. See the second paragraph of Ben Voight's answer below. I don't understand how you can't see that difference. **Moderators have a fairly heavy workload, and making the flag easier to quickly parse and understand is helpful.** The shorter and more clear the flag, the easier it is to understand. Being excessively verbose is simply distracting.

Comment: (continued) To borrow from the TV show *The Big Bang Theory*, there's a difference between telling someone *you're attached to another object by an inclined plane wrapped helically around an axis* and *Dude, you're screwed*. Which is easier to quickly understand?

Comment: @KenWhite: your suggestion is, of course, a little easier to parse overall. I don't deny that. But it is in no way such an enormous difference as to justify declining the flag: the original was more than clear enough. The mod's handling of it was in error. Understandable? Probably. Justifiable? No, not really. Would your suggestion have guaranteed correct handling here? No, not necessarily. This error could have happened anyway.

Comment: @Nathan: Sure, it *could have happened*. With more succinct phrasing, the odds might have been reduced. (I've had several "invalid bounty protected" flags accepted in just the past few days, and none rejected. I've had one declined in the past 6 months, with a note from the mod that read *Declined - Sorry, I didn't get to this in time and the bounty period had expired.*.

Comment: @KenWhite: I did not say that my flag was perfect, I said that I thought all the information in it to be relevant (which are edited out in your version). I have stated why, and you have not provided any reason to contradict it. Perhaps it could have been made more concise - I simply wanted to provide all the needed information in an easy and accessible manner that the moderator would have to check up on anyway. The critical information was in my first sentence, which is as concise as your suggestion. I am open to input, but you don't seem to be open to any dialogue after stating your opinion.

Comment: @KenWhite. Mods who can't be bothered to read should resign their commission.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The decline reason is clearly wrong.  Closure of bountied questions *does* require diamond moderator intervention.  Perhaps the moderator needs to be educated about that, perhaps he wasn't paying attention and didn't notice community closure wasn't possible on *this* question, or perhaps the wrong dispute reason was given and the moderator merely disagreed that the question deserved closure -- but the latter case also implies that the moderator wasn't paying attention to the asker agreeing with closure.

What you could have done better was to specifically draw the moderator's attention to the asker's comment agreeing with the duplicate.  Also, I would have avoided asking the moderator to refund the bounty -- there was return on the bounty in terms of receiving attention and an answer, even if it wasn't a *new* answer.  Let the moderator draw his own conclusion concerning refund.

Comment: It was my impression that closing a bounty question automatically refunds the bounty. That was why I mentioned it.

Comment: I believe the moderator misunderstood the flag reason. They probably did not check the supposed original and **thought that it was the supposed original that has no answers**. Questions generally cannot be duplicates of unanswered questions, [unless on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277950/2157640) or [when the original has the same author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181520/238706).

Comment: @Palec: That is not what the comment declining the flag stated - quite the opposite in fact. Even if the person who declined it had checked only the question under discussion, he would have seen that the answer I referenced was posted there, not on the original duplicate question.

Comment: @corsair992 The comment declining the flag is an automatic one, probably selected from a predefined set, as in any review queue. IMO it’s too general to draw any conclusion about why specifically the mod considered the posts not needing moderator intervention.

Comment: @Palec: Regardless of whether or not it was a canned response, it would have been simply inaccurate and misleading in the case that you describe, or in any other case except the one described by Ben Voigt: the moderator not realizing that the question, being under a bounty, could not be closed by the community.