# Declined mod flag on a bountied question

Tags: discussion, bounty, declined-flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27711058/3204827) question with the following message:

> I am flagging this question because it is asking for personal opinions
>   about how to create a specific type of website. The user hasn't shown
>   anything they have attempted

However, a mod declined the flag (it was a mod flag because it's a bountied question and some threads on this meta said it's best to flag it with a mod) with:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

In my opinion the bountied question should be closed because the user is asking what is the best way to make a website like Ebay or Amazon and they haven't shown anything they have attempted. Is there something I'm not seeing for the reason the flag was declined?

Comment: Closely related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281182/103167; the correct approach is the same.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For future reference, you should include the fact that it is bountied and you can't close it *in the flag reason*. The moderator probably just saw another "this should be closed" flag and declined it without looking. We get a *lot* of these, and very few of them are because of bounties. It's mostly people using the wrong flag reason or not voting to close - situations where the user is perfectly capable of doing something without us, yet for some reason they used a custom flag.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did have it in that it was a bountied question but assumed (I know when you assume you make an ass out of u and me) the mod looking at the question would have something saying the question has a bounty.

Comment: So - we can have hats, but mods can't have a notification on their dealing-with-flagged-questions screen that the the question is bountied and you have to rely on the flagger's notifying you of this matter? My my! Where *is* the sense of priorities?

Comment: @Magoo They *are* working on a complete revamp of the flags queue which will integrate it into the same kind of style as the review queues. I have no idea how far out that is though.

Comment: it would be a nice feature request that shows if there is a bounty on the question.

Comment: Can't we just remove the pointless bounty system? It seems to create more problems than it solves. Or at the very least give the option to user-moderate bounty posts in the same way as any other post?

Comment: @Lundin I don't agree with your first point. The bounty system mostly works as intended in the tag I'm active in. But I agree with your second point. At least users with a gold tag badge should be able to vote to close questions with a bounty.