# Dealing with bounty questions that ask for tutorial, plugin or offsite resource?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounty

I read this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281182/how-to-deal-with-bounty-questions-that-are-duplicates) about bounties that have duplicates, and the discussion went in a direction about flagging moderators.

My situation is a bit different, since the question isn't a duplicate, but asks for a plugin. Not a single line of code, but just: help me find plugin that does this and this and this...

I tried to vote for closing, but since it has a bounty the close vote was declined automatically, so I just downvoted it.

How do we deal with these kinds of questions? Flagging moderator kinda seem too much for this, but then, they are the only ones that could do something about it.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention

Comment: "Flag it for moderator attention with the 'other' flag" And then three weeks later when the flag finally gets handled, the bounty's done and gone.